# django rest framework gives 403 when behind nginx but not directly

Tags: django, nginx, django-rest-framework

Using django-rest-framework.  I'm getting HTTP 403 errors when running in production behind nginx.  When I call a particular view, which inherits from APIView to support a GET operation, I get:

```
{"detail": "Invalid username/password"}
```

But... I only get this in a browser.  I don't get it when I use curl for the very same URL.  I get this error whether I hit the URL directly, or load the URL via AJAX, in both Chrome and Firefox.

I do not get the error if I log in via the Django Admin with an admin account first.

Also, I only get this is I'm running from behind nginx.  If I run with either the Django dev server, or gunicorn, and hit the port directly, I'm fine, and can happily hit the URL anonymously.  If I then put nginx in front of this, to forward to the same gunicorn/runserver I get this error.

Maybe it's something to do with my nginx proxy_pass settings?

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

I'm running django rest framework 2.2.6, Django 1.5 and nginx 1.2.7.

I set throttling to a silly high number in rest framework, and looked at the permissions which all seemed open by default (but set as so explicitly as well).

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Ludo.

Comment: what's your authentication settings for django-rest-framework?

Comment: I'm just using the defaults, which looked suitable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get 403 FORBIDDEN if you have throttling enabled. Based on this issue: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/667, turning off the lazy evaluation of request.user/request.auth is probably the best thing to do.

Comment: Updating to the latest version of REST framework should resolve this issue. (The referenced ticket is now closed)

Comment: Hi.  Thanks!  I'm on 2.2.6 though, which looks like it includes this fix.  I'm trying to follow the thread but cant see an easy way to disable throttling.  I did set a very high throttle value.  Maybe I should try a custom auth class?  I'll try that next I think unless I hear otherwise.  Thanks

Comment: I turned off throttling and auth and everything started working.  Thanks.

Answer (score 26):

In my case, I had HTTP basic authentication configured in Apache, but not in my Django project. Because the request had authentication headers, the Django app thought I wanted to authenticate with it. I disabled authentication in the Django REST framework using these settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': []
}
```

Comment: You don't need to disable all auth classes, only remove basic auth. See  another answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19693433/django-rest-framework-behind-http-basic-authentication

Comment: Excellent.  This was my issue using a VPS + Apache + Passenger (Dreamhost).

Answer (score 4):

If it's a basic http auth (like in @Sjoerd's case) and you don't need a django authentication, you can also remove `Authorization` header in your nginx reverse proxy config:

```
location / {
    ...
    proxy_set_header   Authorization    "";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! We've just run into the same issue, this helped!

Answer (score 3):

When you send a request to the site, which is behind basic authentication,
client (browser) sends 'Authorization' header (as it should - see: "Basic access authentication" on wikipedia).

Ngnix passes it to your application.

Django Rest Framework also supports: BasicAuthentication, and it is enabled by default.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    )
}
```

source: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/

So django-rest-framework sees 'Authorization' header, and thinks that is should be django user with password.

If such user does not exist, then you got: "HTTP 401 Unauthorized".
See: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#basicauthentication

**Soultions**

Pick one:
a) Add to your ngnix site config

```
location / {
    ...
    proxy_set_header    Authorization    "";
    ...
}
```

so DRF will not get 'Authorization' header, so it won't try to match django user.

After this change - basic auth can not be used on django side (empty header!

b) Get rid of "rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication" from REST_FRAMEWORK (in your django settings).

If not defined, add to your django settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    )
}
```

Probbably best solution.

c) Use your django user/password for basic auth?

Realy? - Don't!