# Django Rest Framework behind HTTP Basic Authentication

Tags: django, nginx, django-rest-framework

If my webservice (powered by Django Rest Framework, v2.3.8) is inside a location protected by Nginx's HTTP Basic Authentication, like so:

```
location / {
            auth_basic           "Restricted access";
            auth_basic_user_file /path/to/htpasswd;

            uwsgi_pass django;
            include /etc/uwsgi/config/uwsgi_params;
    }
```

Then, when a user authenticate and tries to access the API, the following response is obtained for all views:

```
{"detail": "Invalid username/password"}
```

Does Django Rest Framework pick up the HTTP Authorization header (meant for Nginx) even though the view requires no authentication? If so, how should I go about this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

By default, Django Rest Framework has two authentication classes, see [here](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/settings.py#L40).

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication'
)}
```

You can disable the rest framework authentication if you don't need it.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': ()
}
```

Or you can remove only `BasicAuthentication` as it will work in your case.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication'
)}
```

Comment: for security reasons dont disallow the default security settings

Comment: This answer works. You can tune application for security when you need security.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in another post, you must add a comma next to the authentication class or it can throw a TypeError.

```
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication', #comma added here
)
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22697034/5687330