# Type error with django framework quickstart

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm getting an error when trying to follow the quickstart example of the Django Rest Framework.  As far as i can tell i've set up everything as needed, I've gone over it a couple of times, but can't seem to find the error
The error is as follows

```
    Environment:


    Request Method: GET
    Request URL: http://webdev.lab.unlab.ca/

    Django Version: 1.6
    Python Version: 2.7.3
    Installed Applications:
    ('django.contrib.admin',
     'django.contrib.auth',
     'django.contrib.contenttypes',
     'django.contrib.sessions',
     'django.contrib.messages',
     'django.contrib.staticfiles',
     'rest_framework')
    Installed Middleware:
    ('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


    Traceback:
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
      114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
      69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
      57.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
      399.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
      387.             self.initial(request, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in initial
      317.         self.check_permissions(request)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in check_permissions
      273.         for permission in self.get_permissions():
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in get_permissions
      226.         return [permission() for permission in self.permission_classes]

    Exception Type: TypeError at /
    Exception Value: 'type' object is not iterable
```

anyone see what's going on?

Comment: You have to post more of your actual code for anyone to help you

Answer (score 17):

The `permission_classes` in your `View/ViewSet` must be a tuple

You wrote something like this:

```
permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated)
```

forgetting a comma.

try with:

```
 permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
```

Comment: There is another stackoverflow post with similar error. [Another comma error in settings.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20519116/typeerror-while-using-django-rest-framework-tutorial)

Answer (score 2):

The variable

```
self.permission_classes
```

in the line:

```
return [permission() for permission in self.permission_classes]
```

does not return a list. And therefore your server is unable to loop over it, i.e. "not iterable".